# Custom component failed with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to write to make my own custom component but it doesn't work as I wish. The interaction seems ok but the it's only render the last item of the arrays.

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            openItems: false,
            selectedItem: 'Please select'
        }
    }

    render() {

        const { items, className } = this.props
        const { openItems, selectedItem } = this.state

        return (
            <div className={classnames('myComponent', className)}>
                <div tabIndex="1"
                    onBlur={() => this.setState({ openItems: false })} 
                    onFocus={() => this.setState({ openItems: true })}>
                    {selectedItem}

                    <div className={classnames({'show': openItems === true, 'hide': openItems === false})}>
                        {items.map((obj, i) => {
                            return(
                                <li onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedItem: obj.name, openItems: false })} 
                                    key={i}>
                                    {obj.name}
                                </li>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and somewhere I used the component like this

```
<MyComponent items={[{
                                    name: 'abc',
                                    name: 'def',
                                    name: 123
                                }]} />
```

I have no clue what the mistake is.

Comment: try to pass an array of object: [{  name: 'abc'},{ name: 'def'},{ name: 123}]
you have only one object in array now.

Comment: hey! there may be some error can you mention the error in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component expects an array of object with the key `name`. When you've initialized your component, you've only passed in a single object with the key `name` duplicated three times:

```
<MyComponent items={[{
  name: 'abc',
  name: 'def', // <-- this overrides the previous 'abc'
  name: 123 // <-- this overrides the previous 'def'
}]} />
```

What you want is this:

```
<MyComponent items={[
  { name: 'abc' },
  { name: 'def' },
  { name: 123 },
]} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be passing the same object `name` thrice, this will override the previous values and the latest value will take the final form.
Consider passing different values with different names.

```
<MyComponent items={[{ name: 'abc',
                      name: 'def',
                      name: 123
                      }]} />
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the props into the constructor method as I am looking you have not passed the props so let's try to add props into the constructor as given below:-

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
       openItems: false,
       selectedItem: 'Please select'
  }
}
```